# How to aviod comma in jstl

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

I use format tag for print decimal value using the below code.

```
<fmt:formatNumber value="${scoreComponentNormalization.rangeEnd}" maxFractionDigits="1" />
```

My expected value is:`2000`

But in prints:`2,000`

How to avoid the comma.Any help will be greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use following in your fmt:formatNumber tag

```
groupingUsed="false" />
```

since by default it is true

Answer (score 2):

You need to use no grouping in jstl while formatting

> groupingUsed: Whether any grouping separated to be used when
>   formatting the output.

```
groupingUsed="false"
```

i.e. `<fmt:formatNumber groupingUsed="false" value="${scoreComponentNormalization.rangeEnd}" maxFractionDigits="1" />`